# Fake live m3u8 stream from static video

Tags: php, sql, nginx, http-live-streaming, m3u8

The backstory is a client who wanted to have a live video stream playing 24/7 with the following requirements:

- If someone connects to the origin and streams, pick it up
- If the origin is audio, add a static image; if not play as is
- If there is no origin, check a pre-programmed "live" stream
- If a pre-programmed stream exists, play that
- If no pre-programmed stream exists, play a random video from a list

So basically, they want to make sure *something* is always playing whenever someone connects to the stream.

What I've done is:

[REAL LIVE]

- Set up an nginx-rtmp-module that writes the m3u8 files

[PROGRAMMED LIVE]

- Control Panel to add assets to programmed stream
- Writes stream info to database

[RANDOM LIVE]

- Script to select random file and play it through

Then I've got a central live.m3u8 that does the following (in order):

1. If m3u8 exists in nginx-rtmp folder, stream through
2. If !m3u8, check database for programmed stream and play that
3. If !program, select random file and stream through
4. If !video, inject static image, else play directly

My DB table is built around the fact that a fixed *start* time for the *first* video *must* be chosen when creating a list and the list will always be contiguous, and creates a continous 24-hour loop around that. For example, if they choose 10 videos of 40 minutes each starting at 1500 hours; then I will create blocks of 400 minutes around that 1500 - 1900 hour window (0300-0700-1100-1500-1900-2300).

This is done by recording in the database the start time of each segment, so my table looks like this:

```
id     order     extinf          start         file
112    100       10.000000       15:00:00      112.ts
113    101       10.000000       15:00:10      113.ts
114    102       10.000000       15:00:20      114.ts
300    103       12.000000       15:00:30      300.ts
301    104       12.000000       15:00:42      301.ts
302    105       12.000000       15:00:54      302.ts
303    106       12.000000       15:01:06      303.ts
```

So that when a user asks for the "live" stream, my query looks like:

```
SELECT
    m3u8.order, m3u8.extinf, m3u8.file, m3u8.start
FROM
    video_hls
WHERE
    m3u8.start >= DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE),'%H:%i:%s') AND m3u8.start <= DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MINUTE),'%H:%i:%s')
ORDER BY
    m3u8.order ASC
```

This trick of selecting the previous minute and the following 3 minutes, plus the use of the #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tag tricks players into thinking they've joined an in-progress live stream and to treat it as such.

Now the problem is that, without fail, whenever someone is watching at the 23:59:59-00:00:00 boundary, they lose the stream and have to reconnect, after that everything is fine.

The "start" column is plain time, my SELECT statement only deals with H:i:s, so there is nothing - that I can see - that should make this happen, the served m3u8 file looks perfectly fine (it works for all other 86398 seconds of the day) and it doesn't hold any date information either, just plain files one after the other.

I can't seem to find any reason at all for this behavior...(I sadly can't share the URL since it's a subscription service - and heavily monitored and protected).

Comment: Personally, I think the issue you are using a 24hour time frame for what should really be a Unix timestamp. Dump the day cycle and use a continuous time frame and things may be easier to manage.

Comment: @Tigger I actually had the timestamp originally but there were several issues, database was enormous and needed daily pruning, and timezoning was wonky (had to do several conversions for different zones); moving to a fixed 24 hour circuit produces max 8640 rows and abstracts timezones, making management easier. Plus, queries are 10% faster between timestamp and time, which adds up with thousands per minute.